# Escape text before piping to sed

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, sed, regular-expression

I am passing to sed for replacement text that seems to have some characters that it does not like.
The text comes from `git log graph` and is something like:

```
ID- desc author                                                                                                   
ID- desc author
```

I get `unescaped newline inside substitute pattern`
How can I escape everything before piping to sed?

```
Example:    
COMMIT=$(git log my_branch...origin/master --pretty=format:'%h %an')    
FINAL=$(cat msg.txt | sed -E "s/--PLACEHOLDER--/$COMMIT/)
```

Comment: Please be more specific. Show us your attempt.

Comment: The error message tells you where the problem is.  But you pose a question asking how to modify _something else instead_.

Comment: @JdeBP: The thing is I don't understand what it complaints about

Comment: Then you should be asking what the error message means, not assuming a meaning for it and proceeding to ask how to do something elsewhere.

Comment: @JdeBP: Please see update

Comment: What does `$COMMIT` contain?

Comment: @Kusalananda: The output of git. I can't see any problem. It is like I mentioned in the post the format

Comment: @Jim I can see that. What I can't see is what the value of `$COMMIT` is that you get on your system with your Git repository.

Comment: @Kusalananda:If I pipe to `od -t a` there is no weird character there. I do see a `nl` in the end of each line but even if I pipe to `tr -d '\n'` I still get the same error

Comment: @Kusalananda: Value is: 
`* SHA1 name  
* SHA1 name  `

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with plain bash parameter substitution:

```
msg=$(< msg.txt)
# or, for this demo
msg="This is the commit message.
--PLACEHOLDER--
That's it."

commit="id1 - message 1
id2 - message 2
id3 - message 3"

final="${msg//--PLACEHOLDER--/"$commit"}"
echo "$final"
```

```
This is the commit message.
id1 - message 1
id2 - message 2
id3 - message 3
That's it.
```

Comment: This works but what's up with the double quote around "$commit"? Works without that